# MBProgressHUD disabling interaction with UITableViewController

Tags: ios, uitableview, mbprogresshud

I'm using an MBProgressHUD inside of a UITableViewController. While I am able to get the HUD to display successfully, the HUD intercepts all of the screen's touch notifications and prevents scrolling in my UITableView.

I know that the intended functionality of MBProgressHUD might be to lock up the interface (say, during a blocking operation), but I want to know how to forward the touch events to the proper places regardless.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 20):

The MBProgressHUD is a subclass of an UIView so you have to disable the user interaction with it. So:

youMBProgressHUDPointer.userInteractionEnabled=NO;

Answer (score 4):

Figured it out. The following code needs to be added to MBProgressHUD's code:

```
- (BOOL)pointInside:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
// UIView will be "transparent" for touch events if we return NO
return (NO);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10590847/mbprogresshud-blocks-interactions-with-an-uiscrollview-when-shown/12948001#12948001). The MBProgressHUD blocks interactions at application level. You need to devise a way to get around that by putting some custom logic.